# findViewById for MenuItem returns null

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

This is my xml file for the ActionBar menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
            android:id="@+id/fav_button"
            android:title="Favourite"
            android:icon="@drawable/unstar"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

In my `onCreate` function, **after** calling `setContentView`. I do `favButton = (MenuItem) this.findViewById(R.id.fav_button);` But this returns null.

But returns the proper object on the `onOptionsItemSelected` function.

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, if that would make a difference.

I have tried various options suggested by other findViewById returns null questions, but they haven't solved my issue.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html. check the link.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Instead of

```
favButton = (MenuItem) this.findViewById(R.id.fav_button);
```

in onCreateOptionsMenu after getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

```
favButton = menu.findItem(R.id.fav_button);
```

Comment: Is there no way to get it during onCreate? I'd like to be able to setChecked()  based on the savedInstanceState Bundle. Alternately, is there a better way to save the checked state of a MenuItem across rotations?

Comment: Can I do it in onCreate?

Comment: It's still null until it gets selected

Comment: mMenu = (Menu) findViewById(R.id.menuBar);
        mMenuItem = mMenu.getItem(2);
        mMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        mMenuItem.setVisible(true); in this mMenu return null

Answer (score 3):

Use menu.findItem() to get the menu. But this needs to be done after the menu is inflated.

Also, to answer your q in comment, you could use onPrepareOptionsMenu to set the state of your menu. If this menu is a one time updating, you could use onCreateOptionsMenu too, which is called only once.

Answer (score 1):

but if someone really needs `View` and not `MenuItem` (for different manipulations, for example to start animation) you can still get it the next way:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.your_menu_xml_file, menu);
    ...
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view = findViewById(R.id.menu_refresh_button);
            // view.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: "post" method is useful for the sake of startAnimation and not because you used findViewById. I.e. without startAnimation, there is no need to use "post". Agree ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
        final Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        Menu menu=toolbar.getMenu();
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.'name id item');
```

for me works.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar                          Toolbar has the method getMenu() that return the Menu shown in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but in my case, I use `findViewById(R.id.menu_id)` return `null`. But I find that I use `findViewById(item.getItemId)` in `onOptionsItemSelected`, it return the view what we want.