# Android : Get the switch button action instead of selected navigation item

Tags: android, android-layout

I have two functions A, B, when the user change the value of the given switch button, A or B will be executed.

my problem is : the actions A, B are executed only when the item is selected but not when the value of switch button changed.

I tried to access the switch button from the onCreate function but i get NullPointerException.

my layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">



    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/switch_status"
            android:title="Go offline"
            android:checkable="true"
            app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
            />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_profile"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_profile"
            android:title="My Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_broadcast"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_broadcast"
            android:title="My groups" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_setting"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

my Activity code :

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, IUserClickListener{

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Utility.updateTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                Fragment f = ((SectionsPagerAdapter) mViewPager.getAdapter()).getFragment(position);
                if ((position == 0 || position == 1) && f != null) {
                    f.onResume();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                updateMyInfo();
            }
        };
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setItemTextColor(new ColorStateList(state, color));
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

// Exception here

final Switch sw = (Switch) menu.findItem(R.id.switch_status);
        sw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (sw.isChecked()) {
Action A;
}
else {Action B;}
        }

}        

        @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.switch_status) {
                Switch sw = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_status);
                if (sw.isChecked()) {
                    Action A
                } else {

                 Action B
            }    
    }
    }
```

How to change my code to execute the action when switch button clicked ?

Thank you

Comment: maybe this answer will help you
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16500596/10022404

Comment: Can you post your complete `onCreate` method?

Comment: still same problem, thank you for your help

Comment: you have my full onCreate now

Comment: can you try with `final Switch sw = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_status);`?

Comment: @Erich where i need to add :
sw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ … ?

Comment: Replace the old line starting with `final Switch sw = ...` with the one I posted.

Comment: not working, the application crash when launched

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211826/discussion-between-erich-and-singa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `onCreate` of the activity is called, the options menu is not inflated yet. That's why `findViewById` can't find your `Switch`.

Add this to your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_drawer, menu);
    final Switch sw = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch_status);
    sw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something
            }
    });
    return true;
}
```

`onCreateOptionsMenu` is called, when your options menu is created, after inflating your menu, you can access the `Switch` as usual.

Comment: This is not a valid answer. He do not need `onCreateOptionsMenu` method, he need to solve problem inside `onNavigationItemSelected`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did, hope it helps somebody:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_dashboard_drawer, menu);
    switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.nav_sync).getActionView();
    this.switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    return true;
}
```